# How do I increment or decrement a column in a update query in Flutter using Drift

Tags: flutter, sqlite, drift

I want to directly update the concerned lines. How do I do that without having to select the items and updating them one by one in Drift?
My current code:

```
      final concernedSongs = await (select(playlistSongs)
            ..where((tbl) => tbl.order.isBetweenValues(low + 1, high)))
          .get(); // should just update and decrement the values without reiterating over them

      concernedSongs.forEach((song) {
        reOrder(song.id, song.order - 1);
      });
```

Comment: Your question is too vague and contains many custom methods which we have no way of understanding. Please simplify the code and be more thorough with what you're looking for otherwise you might not find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom queries, [Reference To Docs](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/using-sql/custom_queries/#custom-update-statements)

this query may help you to get some idea,

```
        await db.customStatement("update 'songs' 
        set order = order-1 where order between ? and ?",
        [low+1,high]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with only dart code at the moment.
You should look into using a [customStatement](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/using-sql/custom_queries/#custom-update-statements). Something like:

```dart
await db.customStatement(
  "UPDATE 'songs' SET order = order - 1 WHERE order > ? AND order < ?",
  [low + 1, high],
);
```